# How to pass attribute for parameter using XQUERY

Tags: xpath, xquery

Hi team,

```
<cars>
     <car id="1">Ford</car>
     <car num="2">Mazda</car>
     <car vol="3">Toyota</car>
     <car soid="4">Lexus</car>
    </cars>
```

XQuery:

```
let $val := 1
let $attr := id
return //car[$attr=$val]
```

I dont know how to pass attribute name in parameter can you please help?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, from XQuery 3.0 you have higher-order functions:

```
let $val := 1
let $attr := function($x){$x!@id}
return //car[$attr(.)=$val]]
```

Answer (score 1):

XQuery is pretty static and doesn't much like dynamic path components. You can leverage `local-name()`:

```
let $val := 1
let $attr := "id"
return //car[@*[local-name()=$attr and data(.)=$val]]
```

This is not particularly efficient, though. Work with static expressions when you can, even if this means a repeating a few conditional expressions here and there.